# New Service Fabric Stateless Web Api Core Project will not compile

Tags: azure-service-fabric, project-template

I open visual studio and do file->new project.

I select cloud->service fabric application.  Then I pick Stateless ASP.NET Core.  In the last window I select Web API and change the authentication to windows authentication.

When I do this and then compile the application, I get errors saying that System.Fabric, Microsoft.ServiceFabric.* are missing.

**How can I get this to work?**

NOTE: I have Visual Studio 2017 15.2.  I downloaded and installed what I think is the most recent tools for service fabric.  My "Extensions and Updates" says I have version 1.6.20170504.1.

**UPDATE - This was due to the project having a dash in the name.  It appears that the template cannot cope with dash casing your project name. (It had nothing to do with Windows Authentication.)**

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE - This was due to the project having a dash in the name.  It appears that the template cannot cope with dash casing your project name.**

This seems to be a problem with the template.  If you don't select Windows Authentication, then it will compile fine.

In a project without windows authentication, the Nuget assemblies are:

- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore
- Microsoft.AspNetCore
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug
- **Microsoft.ServiceFabric**
- **Microsoft.ServiceFabric.AspNetCore.WebListener**
- **Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data**
- **Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services**

When you select Windows Authentication, only the top 4 are added to the project.

**If you add the four missing NuGet packages (the ones in bold above) then the project will compile just fine.**